# How to get type parameters of revit family type?

Tags: ironpython, revit-api, pyrevit

I am trying to create a list of all type parameters using ironpython hosted by pyrevit. I tried following code

```
from pyrevit import revit, DB

doc =__revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
curview = doc.ActiveView

target_category = DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns
elements = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc, curview.Id)\
        .OfCategory(target_category)\
        .WhereElementIsNotElementType()\
        .ToElements()

for ele in elements:
    parameters = [i.Definition.Name for i in ele.Parameters]
    orderedParas = [i.Definition.Name for i in ele.GetOrderedParameters()]

print(sorted(parameters))
print(sorted(orderedParas))
```

Both `ele.Parameters` and `ele.GetOrderedParameters()` could only produce instance parameters.

I have read that instance parameters are type parameters for elements. So i tried to catch family types and applied same code as above.

```
families =   DB.FilteredElementCollector(revit.doc)\
            .OfClass(DB.FamilyInstance)

for family in families:
        x = family.GetOrderedParameters()
        if family.Name == "C2 300x600":
            for i in x:
                print(i.Definition.Name)
```

Unfortunately above code also could produce only instance parametets

Any help in solving this is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more searching i stumbled upon this post [How to access all the family types through revit API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067771/how-to-access-all-the-family-types-through-revit-api?rq=1)
which thankfully had keys to my question

```
from pyrevit import revit, DB

doc =__revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

target_category = DB.BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns
elements = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc)\
        .OfCategory(target_category)\
        .WhereElementIsElementType()\
        .ToElements()

for ele in elements:
    for i in ele.GetOrderedParameters():
        print(i.Definition.Name)
```

It appears i had to use `.WhereElementIsElementType()` instead of `.WhereElementIsNotElementType()` to tap into type properties of Revit family